# Input decompression support in lighttpd

Tags: http, curl, lighttpd

I am trying to send an http PUT request to my lighttpd server with a COMPRESSED file abc.xml.gz  in its body. using curl command by using the `--compressed` option in curl and `-H "Content-Encoding: gzip"` to indicate encoding format.

My question is two pronged :

1. Is there anything else that i need to include in my curl command?
2. What option, if there's any, should I use in lighttpd.conf at the server to support input decompression i.e. to decompress the request object?

To my knowledge mod_compress in lighttpd only supports compressing the contents of the response and not decompressing the request.